# A little confusion on Profile likelihood

Tags: nonparametric, unbiased-estimator, efficiency, profile-likelihood

As we all know, profile likelihood is an effective method for the estimation of conditional parametric model. But I still don't know exactly why it works. Profile likelihood was thoroughly studied by [Severini and Wong](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2242367?&Search=yes&searchText=Wong&searchText=1992&searchText=severini&list=hide&searchUri=/action/doBasicSearch?Query=severini%2b%2526%2bWong%25281992%2529%2b&acc=on&wc=on&prevSearch=&item=1&ttl=104&returnArticleService=showFullText) (1992).

By profile likelihood, can we obtain an unbiased, asymptotically efficient estimator for the parameter? Can we get a unbiased estimator for the nonparametric part?

Comment: Regarding the first question, it is possible to modify the profile likelihood in order to reduce bias (not necessarily to $0$) at least for the exponential family, [see](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/80/1/27.abstract). I am skeptical about the existence of an unbiased estimator asymptotically efficient in the general case.